# Привилегия «site-analytics» не переведена

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Недавно появилась новая [привилегия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics), описание которой полностью не переведено. Нужен перевод заголовка «Access to site analytics» («Доступ к аналитике»?), перевод краткого описания «Access to internal and Google site analytics» («Доступ к собственным данным веб-аналитики и данным Google»?) и перевод всего длинного описания. Сам Google на русскоязычных страницах обычно пишет «аналитика» или «веб-аналитика».

Comment: Проверил, новый текст уже доступен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перевод. Оригинал есть в комментариях (жмите правку) и на страничке [site-analytics](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics)

---

## Доступ к аналитике сайта.

**Что такое аналитика?**

Люди, которые поддерживают сайты, используют данные об использовании этих сайтов для того, чтобы принимать информированные решения. Поскольку наши сайты `[поддерживаются сообществом](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2008/11/stack-overflow-is-you/)`, мы даем самым вовлечённым пользователям особый доступ к части получаемых нами данных. Получив эту привилегию, вы сможете заходить на страницу `[/site-analytics](/site-analytics)` и исследовать собираемые данные, представленные на двух вкладках:

**История**

Здесь представлены три графика, отражающие временную динамику публикуемых сообщений, голосов и траффика. Текстовые поля в верхней части страницы задают границы дат для отображаемых данных.

`![date selectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxoaCl.png)`

[image: date selectors]

`![data series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fRaKs.png)`

[image: data series]

Нажмите на ссылку "csv", чтобы получить отображаемые данные в формате `[CSV](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV)`, пригодном для их дальнейшего анализа. Обратите внимание: в отличие от других источников, таких как `[SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/)`, эти данные включают в себя информацию об удаленных сообщениях.

**Аналитика Google**

На этой вкладке представлены данные `[Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/)` за последние 30 дней. В этих данных есть несколько особенностей:

`*` DuckDuckGo показывается `[как обычный сайт](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/)`, а не поисковая система.

`*` Представленные цифры — на самом деле `[выборка из реальных данных](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121423/analytics-search-keywords-are-unreliable)`, поэтому вы можете увидеть некоторые странности (например, ровно 211 посещений с нескольких поисковых систем).

`*` У нас ограниченная квота на запросы к API, поэтому произвольные интервалы данных не поддерживаются.

`*` Данные по поисковым запросам настолько ненадежны, что мы решили просто не показывать их.

**Как использовать эти данные?**

Поскольку доступ к аналитике является закрытой привилегией, не хотелось бы, чтобы вы размещали сырые данные в общем доступе. Однако, мы рассчитываем на то, что вы поделитесь результатами вашего анализа этих данных с другими участниками на Мете. Например, зрелые сайты сети Stack Exchange как правило получают основную долю трафика из поисковых систем (в частности, из Google). Данные о текущем распределении трафика могут пролить свет на сильные и слабые стороны вашего сайта.

Пожалуйста, не считайте себя обязанным делиться этими данными. (А если у вас ещё нет этой привилегии, то, пожалуйста, не требуйте этого от тех, у кого она есть.) Эта возможность задумана как способ удовлетворить ваш собственный интерес к состоянию сайта и его сообщества.

Comment: @Tagir верно, перевод ещё в работе. Можете смело править, если знаете, как перевести лучше.

Comment: Хотел поправить вступление, но внутри в комментариях не нашел оригинального текста.

Comment: @KromStern: Вот он: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics

Comment: @KromStern: какого именно фрагмента текста там нет? Я вроде бы весь копипастил в исходник, а потом расставлял `<!-- -->`. Там чередуется абзац оригинала — абзац перевода.