# Бюллетень сообщества c 1-го сентября по 4-е октября 2015

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

### Основные показатели

В этом разделе я бы хотел показать основные тенденции сообщества.

#### Сколько людей получило реальную помощь?

**Общая статистика**

```
---------------------
| Вопросы | Ответы  |
---------------------
|   3029  |  4301   |   
---------------------
```

Пример запроса:

```
SELECT count (Id) FROM Posts WHERE PostTypeId = 1 AND CreationDate >= '2015-09-01';
```

Типы сообщений.

- `1` Вопрос
- `2` Ответ

**Ответы**

Принятых ответов: *1 406*.

```
SELECT count (a.Id) FROM Posts a INNER JOIN Posts q on a.ParentId = q.Id WHERE a.PostTypeId = 2 AND a.CreationDate >= '2015-09-01' AND q.AcceptedAnswerId = a.Id;
```

Ответов с голосом положительной оценкой: *2 786*.

```
SELECT count (Id) FROM Posts WHERE PostTypeId = 2 AND CreationDate >= '2015-09-01' AND Score > 0;
```

Количество ответов с отрицательной оценкой: *109*

```
SELECT count (Id) FROM Posts WHERE PostTypeId = 2 AND CreationDate >= '2015-09-01' AND Score < 0;
```

**Скольким людям мы помогли**

На мой взгляд, тут два параметра: 1) количество принятых ответов (обсуждалось выше), 2) количество просмотров страниц.

Google Analytics:

[image: img]

**Сколько новых участников присоединилось к сообществу**

Всего 2 487 человека.

```
SELECT count (Id) FROM Users WHERE CreationDate >= '2015-09-01';
```

### Ценности

**Вклад нашего сообщества в развитие индустрии в целом**

<sub>Заполняется сообществом.</sub>

- Пожалуйста, добавляйте сюда ссылки на публикации о вашем вкладе в развитие индустрии! Это могут быть выступления на конференции, ссылки на обучающие статьи в блоге и т. д.

**Ценность базы знаний**

Было бы интересно дополнительно обсудить этот вопрос. На мой взгляд, ценность базы знаний можно оценить по двум параметрам.

1. *Количеству содержимого (вопросы и ответы)*. *7 330* сообщения.

   ```
   SELECT count (Id) FROM Posts WHERE (PostTypeId = 1 OR PostTypeId = 2) AND CreationDate >= '2015-09-01';
   ```
2. *Количество просмотров в месяц на один вопрос*. (Идея: чем больше людей ищут информацию, тем большему количеству людей она может быть полезна.) *118 258 / 3 029 = 39*.

   ```
   SELECT SUM (ViewCount) FROM Posts WHERE PostTypeId = 1 AND CreationDate >= '2015-09-01';
   ```

   Для всей базы знаний: *1 781 604 / 67 300 = 26*
3. *Баланс голосов «за» и «против»*. «За» – *9 067*, «против» – *1 122*, итог – *+7 945*, то есть в среднем сообщение имеет оценку *+1*.

   ```
   SELECT COUNT (v.Id) FROM Votes v INNER JOIN Posts p on p.Id = v.PostId WHERE v.VoteTypeId = 2 AND p.CreationDate >= '2015-09-01' AND (p.PostTypeId = 1 OR p.PostTypeId = 2);
   ```

<sub>Как мне кажется, было бы интересно ввести показатель аналогичных ВВП и сравнить несколько сообществ, но как должна выглядеть формула? Я бы учитывал количество голосов «за», количество голосов «против», количество вопросов и ответов, размер сообщений, количество просмотров. Буду рад обсуждению!</sub>

**Каким опытом мы обладаем**

Достаточно спорный параметр, который тоже бы было здорово обсудить. В общем, хочется понять, в каких вопросах мы сильны, а каких специалистов следует пригласить в сообщество. На мой взгляд, опыт можно оценивать по следующим критериям.

- *Количество «отвеченных» вопросов* (то есть вопросов с принятым ответом или ответом с голосом «за»). *2 310*.

  ```
  SELECT COUNT  (DISTINCT q.Id) FROM Posts q INNER JOIN Posts a on a.ParentId = q.Id WHERE a.PostTypeId = 2 AND a.CreationDate >= '2015-09-01' AND (q.AcceptedAnswerId = a.Id OR a.Score > 0);
  ```
- *Распределение ответов по меткам*.

[image: img]

```
    SELECT tmp.TheDate, tmp.TagName, COUNT(tmp.TagName) as UseCount 
    FROM (
      SELECT CAST(
              cast(DATEPART(YYYY, a.CreationDate) as varchar) + '-' + cast(DATEPART(MM, a.CreationDate) as varchar) + '-' + cast(DATEPART(DD, a.CreationDate) as varchar) as datetime) AS TheDate, 
            t.TagName
      FROM Tags t 
        JOIN PostTags pt on t.Id = pt.TagId 
        JOIN Posts q on q.Id = pt.PostId 
        JOIN Posts a on a.ParentId = q.Id
      WHERE q.PostTypeId = 1 AND 
      a.CreationDate >= '2015-09-01' AND a.PostTypeId = 2 AND
      t.Id IN 
      (
        SELECT TOP 7 Id FROM Tags 
        ORDER BY Count DESC
      )
    ) AS tmp 
    GROUP BY tmp.TagName, tmp.TheDate
    ORDER BY tmp.TheDate, UseCount DESC;
```

- *Распределение голосов*.

[image: img]

```
    SELECT tmp.TheDate, tmp.TheType, COUNT(tmp.TheType) as UseCount 
    FROM (
      SELECT CAST(
              cast(DATEPART(YYYY, v.CreationDate) as varchar) + '-' + cast(DATEPART(MM, v.CreationDate) as varchar) + '-' + cast(DATEPART(DD, v.CreationDate) as varchar) as datetime) AS TheDate, 
            CASE 
              WHEN v.VoteTypeId = 2 THEN 'UpVote'
              WHEN v.VoteTypeId = 3 THEN 'DownVote'
            END AS TheType
      FROM Votes v 
        JOIN Posts p on p.Id = v.PostId 
        WHERE p.PostTypeId in (1, 2) AND p.CreationDate >= '2015-09-01' AND v.VoteTypeId in (2, 3)
    ) AS tmp 
    GROUP BY tmp.TheType, tmp.TheDate
    ORDER BY tmp.TheDate, UseCount DESC;
```

- *Распределение вопросов по меткам*.

[image: img]

```
    SELECT tmp.TheDate, tmp.TagName, COUNT(tmp.TagName) as UseCount 
    FROM (
      SELECT CAST(
              cast(DATEPART(YYYY, p.CreationDate) as varchar) + '-' + cast(DATEPART(MM, p.CreationDate) as varchar) + '-' + cast(DATEPART(DD, p.CreationDate) as varchar) as datetime) AS TheDate, 
            t.TagName
      FROM Tags t 
        JOIN PostTags pt on t.Id = pt.TagId 
        JOIN Posts p on p.Id = pt.PostId 
      WHERE p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2015-09-01' and
      t.Id IN 
      (
        SELECT TOP 7 Id FROM Tags 
        ORDER BY Count DESC
      )
    ) AS tmp 
    GROUP BY tmp.TagName, tmp.TheDate
    ORDER BY tmp.TheDate, UseCount DESC;
```

### Лучшее из сообщества

#### Лучшее на Мете

- *Публикация с наибольшим количеством откликов* – «[Давайте придумаем метку для всяких полезных мелочей](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1461/6)».
- *Публикация с наибольшим количеством голосов «за»* – «[Какие изменения в привилегиях произойдут после аттестации сайта?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1216/6)».
- *Публикация получившая наибольшее количество просмотров* – «[Куй [железо], пока тематика сайта ещё обсуждается](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1291/6)».

#### Лучшие вопросы Stack Overflow на русском

*Вопрос с наибольшим количеством ответов* - «[Адрес начала массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/448629/6)».

```
SELECT TOP 10 a.ParentId AS QuestionId, COUNT(a.ParentId) AS AnswerCount
FROM Posts q JOIN Posts a on q.Id = a.ParentId
WHERE q.CreationDate >= '2015-09-01' 
GROUP BY a.ParentId
ORDER BY AnswerCount DESC;
```

*Вопрос с наибольшим количеством голосов «за»* – «[Для чего нужен throw new NotImplementedException()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/451540/6)».

```
SELECT TOP 10 Id, Score
FROM Posts 
WHERE CreationDate >= '2015-09-01' AND PostTypeId = 1
ORDER BY Score DESC, CreationDate ASC;
```

*Вопрос получивший наибольшее количество просмотров* – «[Заполнить клетки прямоугольника 2*100 непрерывной последовательностью чисел](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/446659/6)»

```
SELECT TOP 10 Id, ViewCount
FROM Posts 
WHERE CreationDate >= '2015-09-01' AND PostTypeId = 1
ORDER BY ViewCount DESC, CreationDate ASC;
```

#### Лучшие ответы

*Ответ набравший наибольшее количество голосов* – «[Как узнать, откуда был вызван метод?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/449149/6)».
*Самый «быстрый» принятый ответ*  – «[Передача структуры в функцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/450114/6)».

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute , q.CreationDate, a.CreationDate) AS TimeDiff, a.Id
FROM Posts a
  JOIN Posts q on q.AcceptedAnswerId = a.Id
WHERE q.CreationDate >= '2015-09-01' AND q.OwnerUserId != a.OwnerUserId
ORDER BY TimeDiff ASC;
```

*Самый развернутый ответ* – «[Выполнение программы из .ini](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/452045/6)».

```
SELECT LEN(Body) AS Lenght, Id
FROM Posts
WHERE CreationDate >= '2015-09-01' AND PostTypeId = 2
ORDER BY Lenght DESC;
```

### Исправления и улучшения

Изначально планировалось дать этому разделу название «Компания сообществу», но даже не вооруженным взглядом видно, что само сообщество делает для себя намного больше чем Компания для сообщества.

**Список исправленных дефектов**

- [Правка раздела «Что означает статус вопроса закрыт или заморожен»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1064/6).
- [Улучшение раздела справки «Что такое Мета и как она работает?»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1148/6).
- [Редактирование раздела справки «Как выполнять поиск?»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1018/6).
- [Улучшение страницы справки «Что такое Мета и как она работает?»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1148/6).
- [Привилегия «site-analytics» не переведена](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1243/6).
- [33 активности, новая строка!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/120/6).
- [Изменения раздела справки «Будьте дружелюбными»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/928/6).
- [Не переведены элементы меню по закрытию вопроса на основном сайте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1005/6).
- [Не переведены элементы меню по закрытию вопроса на Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1004/6).
- [Не переведен текст на странице Меты «Задать Вопрос»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1042/6).
- [Не переведен текст на странице основного сайта «Задать Вопрос»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/47/6).
- [Английский текст в форме отправки вопроса висит уже полгода. Уберите его наконец оттуда](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1425/6).
- [Как можно перевести системные метки на Мете?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/866/6).

**Список нововведений**

- [Счетчик вопросов/ответов на главной странице](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1281/6).

**Ссылки на посты с последними новостями (о компании, о сообществах, о движке)**

В этом месяце мы достигли порога в [сто вопросв  в день](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1460/6), что действительно очень здорово!

В сентябре [было анонсировано](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1247/6) предложение по расширению движка Stack Overflow – документация, а также [ответы на первые вопросы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1390/6) о новой подсистеме. Для сообщества Stack Overflow на русском Документация станет доступной как только будет понятен набор функций и они пройдут минимальное тестирование.

[Компания сменила имя](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1312/6) со Stack Exchange на Stack Overflow. Теперь сотрудникам компании будет намного проще объяснить, где они работают. Раньше это выглядело так:

> - Вы где работаете?
> - В Stack Exchange.
> - А что это?
> - Это компания, которая сделала Stack Overflow!
> - Так сразу бы так и говорили, что вы из Stack Overflow!

Надеемся, первой фразы будет достаточно.

### Дополнительно

<sub>Требует обсуждения</sub>

**Ссылки на лучшие статьи на других сайтах про сообщества и их аналитика**

<sub>Было бы здорово, если бы этот раздел редактировался всем сообществом. Если вы нашли интересную публикацию про Stack Overflow на русском, или сами написали статью, добавьте ссылку на нее и пару слов о публикации в этот раздел.</sub>

На мой взгляд, наиболее простой способ отследить публикации во внешних сообществах через Google Analytics в источниках переходов.

Наиболее значимое количество пользователей в этом месяце, как ни странно, пришло со статьи «[Секреты Stack Overflow](http://habrahabr.ru/company/Voximplant/blog/266305/)», опубликованной на Хабре пользователем [Grigory Petrov aka @eyeofhell](http://habrahabr.ru/users/eyeofhell/). В статье рассказывается про несколько нюансов, о которых, скорее всего, знают не все участники Stack Overflow.

### В заключение

#### Выводы

- *Первый выпуск*. На мой взгляд, бюллетень получился слишком объемным. Хотелось бы уменьшить количество цифр и добавить больше новостей. Так ли это?
- *Общие выводы*. Сообщество стало намного «сильнее» чем было раньше: возрастание % принятых, уменьшилась время ожидания получения ответа (сравним в следующий раз), ведутся очень активные обсуждение жизни сообщества как в чате, так и на Мете. Спасибо, коллеги!

#### Идеи на следующий месяц<sup>*</sup>

<sub>Скорее всего, на два месяца</sub>

- Как мне кажется, наше сообщество совсем близко подходит к аттестации: все чаще этот вопрос обсуждается среди участников, а ребята из команды развития сообществ Stack Exchange не видят этому преград. Спешу предложить к обсуждению вопрос выдвижения сообщества на аттестацию в ближайшие меся или два. *Что скажите?*
- Как участник сообщества от компании, я постараюсь в будущем месяце сосредоточиться на Мете: исправлении, в первую очередь, дефектов перевода, исправлении недочетов и неясностей в правилах сообщества (по сути, тоже переводы).
- На мой взгляд, возможным «приложением сил» сообщества в этом месяце может стать: процент принятых и привлечение новых участников с интересными вопросами, например, за счет рекомендаций коллегам, задающим вопросы устно, публиковать из в виде вопросов на сайте.
- Было бы здорово провести встречу участников в Москве. [По опыту Санкт-Петербургской встречи](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/790/6), очень интересно познакомиться с участниками сообщества в реальной жизни и вмести портить здоровье за беседой *не* о программировании (хотя бы первые две порчи здоровья). Можно провести её, например, сразу после аттестации.

---

Все данные для публикации получены с помощью [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) – бесплатного сайта, где любой желающий может выполнять SQL-запросы по снимку базы данных любого сайта сети Stack Exchange.

Буду рад обсуждению и предложениям по улучшению содержимого бюллетеня и его формату.

Comment: Цифр и статистики точно надо меньше, эта тонна графиков, на мой взгляд, никому не интересна. Какие выводы читатель может сделать из [этого](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fxfud.png). По-моему, просто визуальный мусор.

Comment: по цифрам не ясно что они означают -- почему именно эти цифры, с чем их сравнивать (с цифрами с других сайтов, с цифрами за лето, ..)? Можно что-то простое упомянуть, например, "в сентябре Stack Overflow на русском вошёл в [пятёрку сайтов по кол-ву задаваемых вопросов](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday), сравнявшись с Server Fault". Или посмотреть как [сравнение с Area51 метриками изменилось с лета](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/875/23044)

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky♦, ты молодец, спасибо за это сообщество. Прочитал интервью на vc.ru и прям загордился, что я почти 4 года здесь.

Comment: Судя по первому графику - многие ходят на сайт с рабочего места :) Данные на графике про метки, ИМХО, нужно группировать хотя бы по неделям, тогда будут видны не просто пики, а общий тренд.

Comment: @ModaL ссылку дайте! )

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, https://vc.ru/p/knowledge-network-stack-overflow

Comment: "Официально я единственный русскоговорящий сотрудник Stack Overflow. " - а как же Anna Lear?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Она «не официально» знает русский язык, в том плане, что она носитель  языка, но никто об этом не знает :)

Comment: Откатил изменения обратно. ))